# json_encode to send data back to js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im creating a simple upload script. I use a simple form to let people upload a picture and then a external php script will upload the picture and return some vars to the upload page.

But I cant get the part to return some vars to work. currently im using this:

The page that also contains the form:

```
form_data.append('file', file_data);
$.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
            dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,                         
            type: 'post',
            success: function(response){
                document.getElementById("titel" + amount).innerHTML = response['naam'];

});
```

The upload page that should return some data:

```
echo json_encode(array('naam'=>$naam));
```

This scripts returns undefined..

If I remove the ['naam'] after response on the form page it will print out:
{"naam":"test.png"}

Hope someone know what im doing wrong.
Thanx in advance!

Comment: why you echo it? return it

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces — Because sending content to STDOUT is out you output data back to the client from PHP and that is what `echo` does. `return` is how you pass it from a function to the calling function *inside* PHP.

Comment: At your situation I will not be echoing anything, I will be returning a json that I will fetch with javascript `response.naam` without parsing. pay attention to datatype

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces — If you don't echo anything then the PHP will output nothing instead of outputting JSON. The PHP return statement does not determine what output the webserver will send to the browser.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces — If you don't parse the HTTP response (assuming it actually contains JSON) then you'll end up with a string. You must parse it. Setting `dataType` correctly causes it to be parsed by the jQuery library so you don't need an explicit parse statement, but it doesn't avoid the need for parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

```
dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
```

… so jQuery will ignore what the server claims the data is (which seems to be HTML as you haven't changed the Content-Type header in your PHP) and process the response as if it was plain text.

`response` will therefore be a plain text string and not the results of parsing JSON.

Change `dataType` to `"json"`.

Answer (score 1):

The response you get from the server is the `string`. To use it as object, you need to parse it to JSON format using `JSON.parse()`.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
```

Then you can use:

```
obj.naam;
```

to get the value of `naam` from the object.

Answer (score -1):

Please change datatype from "text" to "json" then parse that JSON using JSON.parse(//return value ").

Var jsonObject = JSON.parse("Ajax Response object"); 
then use it jsonObject.keyName and it will return the value.

Comment: That will cause jQuery to parse the JSON and populate `response` with the result. Then you try to `JSON.parse` it will be implicitly convert it to something like `"[Object object]"` and then try to parse that as JSON… which will fail.

Comment: Sorry, I interpret the question wrong. As i was expecting JSON object will come from that request through that query. Thanks for correcting me in it.